# How can I deactivate the webcam LED on a ASUS Eee PC Netbook 1001PXD?

Tags: unity, 12.10

On my ASUS Eee PC Netbook 1001PXD my webcam has a little blue LED. When I am working this is disturbing.

How can I switch this Webcam LED of on my netbook?

Comment: This is an English speaking website. I suggested an edit of your german original. Next time I think you should try and translate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there must be a serious hacker with a software answer...
Mine is to use a very little piece of black sello tape.